# Update (refresh) text-label - GTK c-language

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have developed a graphic userinterface for a small program in c. Its some kind of calculator. I have two inputfields where one can enter numbers and I want to display the result as a text-label in the same window.

I do not know how to make the window or the text-label to update itself. I am used with GUIS in java and there are a method called invalidate() to refresh the window and its child-items? Is there a similar function in the gtk3-lib in c?

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand. I think there is a button to press after entering numbers in inputfields, am i right? If so, just connect a function to the button clicked signal.

This function make the sum of 2 numbers and set the label text.

If you don't have the button, i think you need to connect the signal to the inputfields, something like:

```
"on_spinbutton1_value_changed" : update_text_label
```

P.S.
I don't know C, usally i use python, but i think is quite similar.

P.P.S.
Is this the same question founded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905236/refresh-child-items-in-a-container-gtk)?